# Not adding index to document boolean field cause high number of document scan in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Been assigned a project that runs a frequent query to fetch products with a boolean field (`inStock`) , and I am getting alert

> Scanned Objects / Returned has gone above 1000

In Spring Data, it's `findByProductsInStock(boolean flag)` which translates to query `{"inStock": true}`.

The number of products in and out of stock are approximately 50/50. From what I researched a little bit online, placing an index against a boolean field is generally discouraged where ratio of documents in search result is very high. Should I experiment adding the index to this boolean field and measure its performance? and could indexes be added to existing doucments in MongoDB?

Comment: The message _"Scanned Objects / Returned has gone above 1000"_ is a [Query Targeting alert](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/alert-resolutions/query-targeting/) on the MongoDB Atlas Cluster; the link has additional info to resolve the issue. (1) _"could indexes be added to existing doucments in MongoDB?"_: Yes, indexes can be added to existing collections (in general), (2) _"Should I experiment adding the index to this boolean field and measure its performance? "_: You have the best knowledge about your application and data.

Comment: You may want to post additional information about the collection, the query and its usage for any specific answers.

Comment: Yes, you should experiment with adding the index to this boolean field. Yes, you can also add index to existing documents. I'm not sure there is a problem with placing index on boolean fields, maybe you can share your sources.

Comment: Scanned / Returned ratio of 1000 to 1 contradicts your assumption of 50/50

Comment: Yes. My assumption was incorrect. It was a completely different query that caused the issue.